# AWS access restricted by public IP or VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to use an IAM policy to restrict access for all AWS resources to either a public IP or a VPC.  Documentation suggests this should work and it seems to work fine for the IP case.  But as soon as I add the condition for the VPC, it breaks.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddressIfExists": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "a.b.c.d/32"
            },
            "StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
                "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-1234wxyz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What documentation did you follow?

Comment: There is some syntax error in your policy that is causing the issue.

Comment: Define *"it breaks."*  `aws:sourceVpc` has very few current uses.  In fact, [only one](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html) that I know of.

Comment: @error2007s - I followed the policy documentation in the IAM reference guide. And I'm not sure what syntax error you're referring to; The policy validation succeeds.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot - "It breaks" was a poor choice of words.  But once I attach the policy to my user, I'm no longer able to access S3 from the VPC.  I can still access it from the public IP address.

Comment: Did you try to access S3 from Private subnet or public subnet of your VPC?

Answer (score 1):

In a "Deny" Statement, if any of the Conditions are satisfied the request will be denied.

For requests coming from outside of your VPC, "aws:SourceIp" exists and "aws:sourceVpc" does not exist, so it only evaluates your "aws:SourceIp" condition.

For requests coming from inside of your VPC, "aws:SourceIp" exists and "aws:sourceVpc" exists, so it evaluates both. Since you are inside your VPC that condition allows access, but since your source IP is the IP of your AWS instance that condition denies access.

Basically, the problem is you are relying on "IfExists" with the assumption that only one or the other will exist, but inside your VPC both exist. There is a [special case](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#AvailableKeys) for this, only if the request comes via an [Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html#vpc-endpoints-iam-access) (such as to S3):

> **Note**
>
> If the request comes from a host that uses an Amazon VPC endpoint,
>   then the aws:SourceIp key is not available. You should instead use a
>   VPC-specific key. For more information, see VPC Endpoints -
>   Controlling the Use of Endpoints in the Amazon VPC User Guide.

Only in that special case, Amazon removes "aws:SourceIp" which would make your "IsExists" work.